# jquery and css set position based on div in other wrapper

Tags: jquery, css, position

I have two wrapper divs side by side. I want to line up divs in the right column to match the position of select divs in the left column.

In the fiddle, each div in the right column should be lined up with the top of every second div in the left column. There should be one div [x] per two divs on the left.

It's all dynamically created which is why I've made the fiddle the way it is http://jsfiddle.net/sKZXJ/

HTML:

```
<!-- Extra height added because that seems part of the problem -->
<div style="height:60px;"></div>

<div id="scroller">
    <div id="wrapper1"></div>
    <div id="wrapper2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#scroller {
    height:300px;
    width:60px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
#wrapper1 {float:left; width:15px;}
#wrapper2 {float:left; width:15px;}
.littleOne {
    margin-top:1px;
    position:relative;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#006600;
}
.littleTwo {
    margin-top:1px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#00CCCC;
}
```

THE FUN PART:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Fill wrapper1 with divs
    for(var i=0;i<50;i++) {
        $('#wrapper1').append('<div id="a'+i+'" class="littleOne"></div>');
    }

    // Add selected divs to wrapper2 in matching positions
    var pos = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<50;i+=2) {
        $('#wrapper2').append('<div id="b'+i+'" class="littleTwo">X</div>');
        pos = $('#a'+i).position().top - $('#scroller').position().top;
        $('#b'+i).css('top', pos+'px');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/f5ArU/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Fill wrapper1 with divs
    for(var i=0;i<50;i++) {
        $('#wrapper1').append('<div id="a'+i+'" class="littleOne"></div>');
    }

    // Add selected divs to wrapper2 in matching positions
    var pos = 0;
    var offset = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<50;i+=2) {
        var b = $('<div id="b'+i+'" class="littleTwo">X</div>');
        $('#wrapper2').append(b);
        pos = $('#a'+i).position().top - offset;
        offset += b.height() + 1;
        b.css('top', pos+'px');
    }

});
```

Comment: That's what I'm after, however your example didn't compensate for the margin so I added it here `offset += b.height()+1;` Thanks @Kroehre

Comment: yep, i updated the fiddle with that, (that's why we use fiddles @Roko)

Comment: Dear Kroehre, SO cannot relay on trd parties and broken links. Keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: @Roko nor can it survive with condescending users. Your edit impeded my ability to sufficiently help the op, SO's primary purpose. I don't disagree with your point about third parties but a simple comment to bring the code in will suffice. Keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: I posted you a comment - waited and I removed it afterwards I changed your post. I'm really interested in how that could be harmful for you. Thanks. Sorry

Comment: Because I was unaware my post was changing. I made corrections to my fiddle which weren't visible here. A simple comment would have nicely asked me to move it, so then i would have made my edits here. I really do appreciate you looking out for the SO community, but education is far more effective than policing.

Comment: Also please keep in mind that jsfiddle is much more effective for answering questions that involve script, markup, and css. I think its a great idea to bring that code in once an answer has been arrived at, but ultimately I'm here to help people and frankly jsfiddle does a better job of facilitating that while we're working towards an answer.

Comment: It may just be my browser, but do you guys see a shifting issue show up as you scroll down?

Comment: @rkw Yeah, that was the issue we were referring to with the +1. Take a look now.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/sKZXJ/1/

Just used `scrollTop` in one place instead of `top` (if that's what you meant though).

Comment: Sorry that's not what I'm after, see the edited second paragraph in my question.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to line up divs in the right column to match the position of select divs in the left column."

You can manage with this code 
example -
I have updated your link  http://jsfiddle.net/sKZXJ/2/   - CHANGING BACKGROUND COLOR

```
$("#wrapper1 div").click(function () {
$('#wrapper2 div:eq('+($(this).index())+')').css('background-color','#000');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that makes use of html structure and css: http://jsfiddle.net/sKZXJ/6/

It's an alternative that attempts to separate your logic from your layout.  The fact that the tiny 'x' only shows up on every other green block makes me assume that each 3 block should be logically grouped.

html:

```
<div id="scroller"></div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Fill wrapper1 with divs
    for(var i=0;i<50;i+=2) {
        var one = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'a'+i).addClass('littleOne'),
            two = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'b'+i+1).addClass('littleTwo'),
            three = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'a'+i+1).addClass('littleOne'),
            container = $('<div></div>').addClass('container').append(one).append(two).append(three);

        $('#scroller').append(container);
    }    
});​
```

css:

```
#scroller {
    height:300px;
    width:60px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
.container {
    width: 40px;
}
div {
    margin: 1px;
    width: 15px;
}
.littleOne {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#006600;
}
.littleTwo {
    float: left;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#00CCCC;
}    ​
```